# Need a jQuery calendar plugin, specific dates

Tags: jquery, plugins

I need a jQuery calendar plugin where I can specify what dates are selectable but still show an entire month on the calendar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/), just add handlers to the events that check the dates.

**Sample** (Original from [this forum post](http://www.nabble.com/How-make-just-a-few-dates-selectables--td25537635s27240.html))

```
<script type="text/javascript">

      $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#datepicker").datepicker({
              dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yyyy',
              beforeShowDay:  disableDays
        });
      });

      var disabledDays = ["12/10/2009", "13/10/2009", "15/11/2009"];

      function disableDays(date) {

              var sDate = date.getDate().toString() + "/" + 
                          (date.getMonth()+1).toString() + "/" + 
                          date.getFullYear().toString();
              if ($.inArray(sDate, disabledDays ) != -1) return [true];
              else return [false];

      }

  </script>
```

**Another sample** (faster?) from [here](http://jsbin.com/enaza/edit)

```
$(function() {
    // format: specialDays.year.month.day
    var specialDays = {
          '2009': {
        '1': {'1': {tooltip: "New Year's Day", className: "holiday"}},
        '4': {
           '10': {tooltip: "Good Friday", className: "holiday"}, 
           '13': {tooltip: "Easter Monday", className: "holiday"}
            },
        '5': {
            '4': {tooltip: "Early May Bank Holiday", className: "holiday"},
            '15': {tooltip: "Spring Bank Holiday", className: "holiday"}
            },
        '8': {'31': {tooltip: "Summer Bank Holiday", className: "holiday"}},
        '12': {
            '25': {tooltip: "Christmas Day", className: "holiday"},
            '28': {tooltip: "Boxing Day", className: "holiday"}
            }
        }
    }; 

    $('#datepicker').datepicker({beforeShowDay: function(date) {
               var d = date.getDate(),
           m = date.getMonth()+1,
           y = date.getFullYear();

        if (specialDays[y] && specialDays[y][m] && specialDays[y][m][d]) {
           var s = specialDays[y][m][d];
             return [true, s.className, s.tooltip]; // selectable
        }
        return [false,'']; // non-selectable
    }});
});
```

Comment: Needed to use the beforeShowDay event: http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker#event-beforeShowDay

Answer (score 1):

jCal is great at this and very customizeable.

[jCal homepage](http://www.overset.com/2008/05/12/multiday-calendar-datepicker-jquery-plugin/)

This will show 1 month and only have the 3 days specified allowed to be selected.

```
        $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#calOne').jCal({
            day: new Date((new Date()).setMonth(7)),
            days: 1,
            showMonths: 1,
            dayOffset: 0,
            dow:     ['S', 'M', 'T', 'W', 'T', 'F', 'S'],
            dCheck:         function (day) { return $.inArray(
            [(day.getMonth() + 1), day.getDate(), day.getFullYear()].join('/'),
            ['8/21/2009', '8/28/2009', '8/29/2009']) != -1},
            callback: function (day, days) {
                    $('#calResult').val(day.getFullYear() + '-' + ( day.getMonth() + 1 ) + '-' + day.getDate());
                    return true;
                }
            });
  $('#calOne').disableSelection();
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [yacal](http://eduludi.github.io/jquery-yacal/). It's lightweight and allows you to directly choose a date range (min/max dates).

```
$('.calendar').yacal({
  minDate: '2009/11/10',
  maxDate: '2009/11/20',
})
```